# How do I use dotnet test to run tests from multiple libraries with a single pass/fail summary

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

How do I run unit tests with `dotnet test` if I have multiple test libraries in a code base?

I can run `dotnet test`, and it will find and run all tests even across multiple libraries, but it runs and reports each test library run independently:

```
$ dotnet test
Test run for C:\Users\mark\Documents\Redacted.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Redacted.Test.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
Test run for C:\Users\mark\Documents\Redacted\Redacted.SqlAccess.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Redacted.SqlAccess.Test.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.2.0-preview-20190606-02
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.2.0-preview-20190606-02
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
Starting test execution, please wait...

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 59
     Passed: 59
 Total time: 3.1779 Seconds
Test run for C:\Users\mark\Documents\Redacted\Redacted.RestApi.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Redacted.RestApi.Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.2.0-preview-20190606-02
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 99
     Passed: 99
 Total time: 9.8155 Seconds

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 25
     Passed: 25
 Total time: 21.2894 Seconds
```

In this example, there's two test libraries, so I get two test result outputs.

This may work OK if the code has already been compiled, but in a clean build, there's going to be a lot of output from the compiler. This can easily cause one of the **test run summaries to scroll past the visible part of the screen**.

That's a problem if that test run fails.

How can I collapse all the unit tests to a single pass/fail summary?

---

On .NET 4.x, I could, for instance, use xUnit.net's console runner to run all test libraries as a single suite:

```
$ ./packages/xunit.runner.console.2.4.0/tools/net461/xunit.console BookingApi.UnitTests/bin/Debug/Ploeh.Samples.Booking
Api.UnitTests.dll BookingApi.SqlTests/bin/Debug/Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.SqlTests.dll
xUnit.net Console Runner v2.4.0 (64-bit Desktop .NET 4.6.1, runtime: 4.0.30319.42000)
  Discovering: Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.UnitTests
  Discovered:  Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.UnitTests
  Starting:    Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.UnitTests
  Finished:    Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.UnitTests
  Discovering: Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.SqlTests
  Discovered:  Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.SqlTests
  Starting:    Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.SqlTests
  Finished:    Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.SqlTests
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.SqlTests   Total:  3, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 3.816s
   Ploeh.Samples.BookingApi.UnitTests  Total:  7, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 0.295s
                                              --          -          -           -        ------
                                 GRAND TOTAL: 10          0          0           0        4.111s (5.565s)
```

Notice how this produces **a single summary** at the bottom of the screen, so that I can immediately see if my tests passed or failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `dotnet vstest` to run multiple assemblies.

```
 PS> dotnet vstest --help

Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Usage: vstest.console.exe [Arguments] [Options] [[--] <RunSettings arguments>...]]

Description: Runs tests from the specified files.

Arguments:

[TestFileNames]
      Run tests from the specified files. Separate multiple test file names
      by spaces.
      Examples: mytestproject.dll
                mytestproject.dll myothertestproject.exe
...
```

Note that this method requires that you point at compiled assemblies (as opposed to `dotnet test`, which wants you to point at project files, and will optionally build things first for you).

Comment: *"will optionally build things first for you"* That sounds even better! It doesn't seem to do this automatically, though, so how do I enable that? The documentation didn't seem to say.

Comment: @MarkSeemann You can't do that with `dotnet vstest`, but `dotnet test` will automatically build for you if it's not already built (you have to pass `--no-build` to `dotnet test` to get it to stop doing that).